# I have a question regarding the logic of this Java program. It should go into the first if/else statement, but it does not?

Tags: java, if-statement

Since 31 > 8,  is should go into the first if statement, and since 31 < 100, it then should go into the else statement and output "hi". However the output of this program is "ther3". I do understand that `System.out.print("ther3");` is outside both if statements and would be printed regardless. But why is `System.out.print("hi");` not printed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 31;
    int y = 8;
    if (x > y) {
        if (x > 100) {
            System.out.print("Hello");
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.print("hi");
    System.out.print("ther3");
}
```

Comment: Format the code correctly and you will see why it doesn't work

Comment: I formatted it the exact way my professor did

Comment: Now it's formatted correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it didn't print "hi" is because the `else` part belongs to the `outer` if statement not `inner`.
You can see the curly braces `{}` of the outer if statement. It's closed before else. That's why it's not executed. You can change it and see the output once.

```
if (x > y) {
   if (x > 100) { 
      System.out.print("Hello"); 
   } 
}
else
   System.out.print("hi");
System.out.print("ther3");
```